# ASP .net : register custom control from .vb code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, custom-controls

I try to create custom control, loaded dynamically from .vb code.

Here is my custom control "ControlCar" in file "controlcar.ascx"

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" ClassName="ControlCar" %>
<script runat="server">
    Private m_car As Car = Nothing
    Public Property Car() As Car
        Get
            Car= m_car
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Car)
            m_car = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Sub Panel_OnLoad(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        If Me.m_car Is Nothing Then
            lit_color.Text = "(m_car Is Nothing)"
        Else
            lit_color.Text = "color of Me.m_car is (" & Me.m_car.Color & ")"
        End If
    End Sub

</script>

<asp:Panel ID="panel" OnLoad="Panel_OnLoad" runat="server">
    this is a car<br />
    color = <asp:Literal ID="lit_color" runat="server"></asp:Literal><br />
    <br />
</asp:Panel>
```

Here is my ASP web page in file "cars.aspx" which use .vb code for events, ...

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" Explicit="true" Inherits="PageBase" Src="/code/cars.vb"%>

<html>
<body>
    <!-- Html code here --->
    <asp:panel ID="panel_cars" runat="server">
    </asp:panel>
</body>
```

And here is my .vb code in file "cars.vb"

```
    Private Sub CreateCar()
        Dim car As Car = new Car()
        Dim control As ControlCar = Nothing
        control= CType(LoadControl("/code/controlcar.ascx"), ControlCar)
        control.Car = car
        panel_cars.Controls.Add(control)
    End Sub
```

**But it fails, saying 'ControlCar' is unrecognized** in cars.vb.

I know it works, if move .vb code in .aspx file and using directive

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="ControlCar" Src="/code/controlcar.ascx" %>
```

But I need to separate .vb code and .aspx code like in my example.

How can I make recognizing 'ControlCar' type (defined in .ascx) in .vb file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some kind of reference. You can use a reference directive:

```
<%@ Reference Control="controlcar.ascx" %>.
```

The control is being dynamically compiled. If you have no reference, the compiler has no idea what you are trying to use.

EDIT:

You may be able to use:

```
Imports ASP.controlcar_ascx
```

If the reference must be in the code behind. I have had issues with this in the past though.

Comment: @TheFrancisOne The Question is about ASP.NET. Did you really down vote this?